# User and UserProfile objects in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I'm having some trouble with a related field to User in my UserProfile model.

I have this field in my UserProfile model:

```
friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True)
```

When I call

```
User.objects.get(pk=234).get_profile().friends.all()
```

I get the set of friends as User objects

When I call

```
User.objects.get(pk=234).friends_set.all()
```

I get a list of UserProfile objects.

Is there a way (without changing the relationship to be with a UserProfile object) to get each side of the relationship returned as either User or UserProfile?

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion i figured out what i was trying to do:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=234)
User.objects.filter(userprofile__friends=user).all()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want User objects or UserProfiles?

Comment: I want either - as long as I can get the same for each side of the relationship. Right now I can only get UserProfiles for one side and User for the other side.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is the way to select the `UserProfile` objects which are friends with a given user:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(friends__user = 234)
```

And here are the `User` objects for the same set of users:

```
User.objects.filter(userprofile__friends__user = 234)
```

Comment: Sorry i had a typo in my question - i get one side of the relationship as User objects and the other as UserProfile. How would I get both sides of the relationship as UserProfile?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't just one relationship so there is more then just the two sides you are considering. A user has a relationship with a profile object (FK) and another with numerous user objects (M2M).